# Svelte access a store variable in child component script tag

Tags: store, svelte, sapper, svelte-3

I have a Svelte & Sapper app where I am using a Svelte writable store to set up a variable with an initial blank string value:

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
export let dbLeaveYear = writable('');
```

In my `Index.svelte` file I am importing this and then working out the value of this variable and setting it (I am doing this within the `onMount` function of ```Index.svelte if this is relevant):

```
<script>
  import {dbLeaveYear} from "../stores/store.js"

  function getCurrentLeaveYear() {
    const today = new Date();
    const currYear = today.getFullYear();
    const twoDigitYear = currYear.toString().slice(-2);
    const cutoffDate = `${twoDigitYear}-04-01`
    const result = compareAsc(today, new Date(cutoffDate));
    if (result === -1) {
      $dbLeaveYear = `${parseInt(twoDigitYear, 10) - 1}${twoDigitYear}`;
    } else {
      $dbLeaveYear = `${twoDigitYear}${parseInt(twoDigitYear, 10) + 1}`;
    }
  }

  onMount(() => {
    getCurrentLeaveYear();
  });
</script>
```

I have a child component being rendered in the `Index.svelte`

```
<Calendar />
```

Inside the Calendar child component I am importing the variable and trying to access it to perform a transform on it but I am getting errors that it is still blank - it is seemingly not picking up the assignment from `Index.svelte`:

```
<script>
  import {dbLeaveYear} from "../stores/store.js"
  const calStart = $dbLeaveYear.slice(0, 2)
</script>
```

However if I use the value in an HTML element in the same Calendar child component with `<p>{$dbLeaveYear}</p>` it is populated with the value from the calculation in `Index.svelte`.

How can I access the store variable inside the `<script>` tag of the child component?  Is this even possible?  I've tried assiging in `onMount`, I've tried assigning in a function - nothing seems to work and it always says that `$dbLeaveYear` is a blank string.

I need the value to be dynamic as the leave year value can change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is a combination of Sapper preload and the ability to export a function from a store.

in `store.js` export the writable store for the variable you want and also a function that will work out the value and set the writable store:

```
export let dbLeaveYear = writable('');

export function getCurrentLeaveYear() {
  const today = new Date();
  const currYear = today.getFullYear();
  const twoDigitYear = currYear.toString().slice(-2);
  const cutoffDate = `${twoDigitYear}-04-01`
  const result = compareAsc(today, new Date(cutoffDate));
  if (result === -1) {
    dbLeaveYear.set(`${parseInt(twoDigitYear, 10) - 1}${twoDigitYear}`);
  } else {
    dbLeaveYear.set(`${twoDigitYear}${parseInt(twoDigitYear, 10) + 1}`);
  }
}
```

In the top-level `.svelte` file, use Sapper's `preload()` function inside a `"module"` script tag to call the function that will work out the value and set the writable store:

```
<script context="module">
  import {getCurrentLeaveYear} from '../stores/store'
  export async function preload() {
        getCurrentLeaveYear();
  }
</script>
```

And then in the component `.svelte` file, you can import the store variable and because it has been preloaded it will be available in the `<script>` tag:

```
<script>
  import {dbLeaveYear} from '../stores/store'

  $: startDate = `20${$dbLeaveYear.slice(0, 2)}`
  $: endDate = `20${$dbLeaveYear.slice(-2)}`
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Before digging deeper into your problem, let me say that you shouldn't mutate the store variable directly, but use the provided set or update method. This avoids hard-to-debug bugs:

```
  if (result === -1) {
      dbLeaveYear.set(() => `${parseInt(twoDigitYear, 10) - 1}${twoDigitYear}`);
    } else {
      dbLeaveYear.set(`${twoDigitYear}${parseInt(twoDigitYear, 10) + 1}`);
    }
```

With that out of the way, the problem seems to be that your [auto-subscribe](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/auto-subscriptions) to the store is not ideal for your use case. You need to use the subscribe property for that:

```
<script>
  import { dbLeaveYear } from "../stores/store.js"
  import { onDestroy, onMount } from "svelte"

  let yearValue;
  // Needed to avoid memory leaks
  let unsubscribe

  onMount(() => {
    unsubscribe = dbLeaveYear.subscribe(value => yearValue = value.slice(0, 2));
  })

  onDestroy(unsubscribe);
</script>
```

Another thing that could cause your problem is a race condition. So the update from the parent component is not finished when the child renders. Then you would need to add a sanity check in the rendering child component.

Comment: Thanks for the post.  I'm slightly confused though by you saying the issue is with me using the $ syntax as this is perfectly valid auto-subscription syntax as described on the svelte site and tutorial - https://svelte.dev/tutorial/auto-subscriptions

Comment: I guess you are right. Seems more like the problem is that you manipulate the variable when mounting the component which is potentially undefined at that point. Also it is evil, as there are getters and setters around which could cause bugs. Have you tried my syntax?

Comment: I’ll try it this weekend and let you know. Thanks for following up.

Comment: So I think this is Sapper/SSR realted rather than Svelte/Store related as I rewrote the code to make it a local variable in Index.svelte and passed it to Calendar.svelte as a prop and it still comes out blank.  Reading the docs on Sapper I think it is because I am doing all the calcluations on the varaibles in the onMount function which only runs on the client so at the point of evaluating the code in my <script> tag the vaiable is still the initally declared bank string.  I somehow need to do the calcuations server side so I am investigating how.

Comment: Ah, ok. Unfortunately, I have no experience with Sapper, so I won't be of any help there. Good luck.